# Discord python run Client() and Bot() at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to prevent some friends from over-using a command by using :

```py
@commands.cooldown(2, 6, commands.BucketType.user)
```

The problem is that I use mainly Client() and this decorator doesn't seem to work when I use it. This problem would go away if I used Bot() instead but I can't run those 2 elements at the same time, and the rest of my code uses Client(). So I have :

```py
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
```

And I wonder if there is a way to use both or to do it as simple as that using already existing library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`commands.Bot` inherits from `discord.Client`. That means that *anything* you can do with `discord.Client`, you can also do with `commands.Bot`.

Using `commands.Bot` is just far more convenient for making a discord bot.

---

**Reference:**

- [`commands.Bot()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) - "This class is a subclass of `discord.Client` and as a result anything that you can do with a `discord.Client` you can do with this bot."